# Is it possible to output to and monitor streams other than stdin, stdout & stderr? (python)

Tags: python, linux, macos, terminal, stdout

This is a python question, but also a linux/BSD question.

I have a python script with two threads, one downloading data from the web and the other sending data to a device over a serial port. Both of these threads print a lot of status information to stdout using python's `logging` module.

What I would like is to have two terminal windows open, side by side, and have each terminal window show the output from one thread, rather than have the messages from both interleaved in a single window.

Are there file descriptors other than stdin, stdout & stderr to write to and connect to other terminal windows? Perhaps this wish is better fulfilled with a GUI?

I'm not sure how to get started with this.

edit: I've tried writing status messages to two different files instead of printing them to stdout, and then monitoring these two files with `tail -f` in other terminal windows, but this doesn't work for live monitoring because the files aren't written to until you call `close()` on them.

Comment: "I have an inkling that it may be possible to achieve this by writing status messages to two separate files". I assume you haven't tried that yet though? You can set the logging to let each thread log to a separate file (by letting each thread use a separate logger). If you want to go the GUI way, you may want to have a look at the more exotic logging handlers such as the QueueListener.

Comment: I just tried it using python's built-in file writing methods and it didn't work (see edit above).

Comment: If you had to call `close()`, that likely means you didn't use logging FileHandlers? You can also call `fp.flush()` on the file pointers to force a line to be written to file.

Answer (score 2):

First, customize your logging formatter to include a **Thread id** field (https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes). Then change your logging destination to some file instead of stdout.

```
# A simple logger as print
import logging
import logging.handlers

hdr = logging.FileHandler(filename='output.log')
hdr.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] thread=%(thread)s:%(levelname)s: %(message)s'))
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(hdr)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

import threading


def func():
    logger.info('test message')


for i in range(2):
    threading.Thread(target=func).start()
```

Your logging output may look like this now:

```
% tail -f output.log
[2015-09-28 15:14:49,782] thread=4344852480:INFO: test message
[2015-09-28 15:14:49,782] thread=4349059072:INFO: test message
```

Run your script, open two individual terminals, and use the command `tail -f output.log | grep thread=<THREAD_ID>` to monitor logs by thread ID.

Comment: Nice! I hadn't thought of doing it this way, and it's a nice way to get the desired display without splitting output into multiple log files. Tested and it works!

Answer (score 0):

File write operations are buffered by default so the file isn't effectiveley written until either the buffer is full, the file is closed or you explicitely call `flush()` on the file.

But anyway: dont use direct file access if you want to *log* to a file, use either a `logging.StreamHandler` with an opened file as stream or, better, a `logging.FileHandler`. Both will take care of flushing the file.